# How to make UI in flutter like the image attached?

Tags: flutter

[image]

Any Help will be appreciated in this regard.

Thank you

I tried different ways but couldn't able to achieve like this

Comment: Are you revering the to the steps?  Can you include what you;ve tried so far?

Comment: I am pretty new to flutter. I have started with this but couldn't able to figure it out.

Comment: Try  `Stepper` widget, but may be miss the gradient ui. you might need to  create widget with Custompaint

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Stepper`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) widget. Also you can check [im_stepper](https://pub.dev/packages/im_stepper) package.

Doc example of `Stepper`

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stepper(
      currentStep: _index,
      onStepCancel: () {
        if (_index > 0) {
          setState(() {
            _index -= 1;
          });
        }
      },
      onStepContinue: () {
        if (_index <= 0) {
          setState(() {
            _index += 1;
          });
        }
      },
      onStepTapped: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _index = index;
        });
      },
      steps: <Step>[
        Step(
          title: const Text('Step 1 title'),
          content: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: const Text('Content for Step 1')),
        ),
        const Step(
          title: Text('Step 2 title'),
          content: Text('Content for Step 2'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```